# Removing a - and a U from a list of numbers in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a column called 'Last Form' in pandas df with various numbers in. There is also a - symbol and letter U in the column

eg

```
 1    
 3    
 U    
 4    
 -    
 5    
 U
```

How do I get rid of the - and U?

I've tried:

```
df['Last Form'] = df['Last Form'].replace('U', '')
df.replace('-', 0, inplace=True)
```

And I keep getting this error when I use `>=2` to filter the results.:

```
TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df['Last Form'] = df['Last Form'].replace({'U': '', '-': 0})
```

Or, for numbers:

```
df['Last Form'] = pd.to_numeric(df['Last Form'].replace({'U': '', '-': 0}), errors='coerce')
```